# How can the user open Maps from a table view cell in my App

Tags: xcode, dictionary, sdk, uiapplication

Im trying to open Maps from my App from a table view cell, I know I need this code in my AppDelegate.m file:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=Our+Lady+Queen+of+Peace+Catholic+Church+Greystanes"
```

I would like the saddr to be the user's and direct to the location address as above.

How do I link a table view cell to that code ?

Answer (score 0):

You would do this inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the `ViewController` that controls that `TableView` (not in the `AppDelegate`).  Build that url with the data you need in that cell (hopefully coming from a backing data source) and then use the code you have above.  Something like this:

```
NSDictionary *thisCell = [myTableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com.au/maps?q%@", [thisCell valueForKey:@"locationKey"]]]];
```

Comment: Hi, I'm very new to developing Apps would you be able to describe this in more detail. how do I access the viewController that controls the TableView, it is not in the viewController.m so where do I find it ?

Comment: What part of your application displays a tableview?  That "scene" would have a view controller (or a tableview controller) backing it.  Do you have a tablieview somewhere in your application right now?

Comment: Yes I can locate the tableView and tableview Controller in mainstoryboard.storyboard

Comment: You need to have a custom class as the parent of that TableView.  You would then set that to be the parent of your Storyboard scene TableViewController.

Comment: If all this is foreign to you, you really need to take an Intro to iOS development course of some kind.  The Stanford one (on iTunesU) is a great choice assuming you already have a development background in some other object oriented language.